# Are there any cheaper alternatives to the SM81?

Tags: microphone, home-studio

I'm wanting a good mic for recording an acoustic guitar in my home studio. Everything I read says the SM81 is the way to go. But at $350 new it's a bit more then what I can spend. Can anyone recommend a few decent alternatives?

Comment: What's your limit on spending?

Comment: I'd like to keep at around $150 or less

Comment: suggesting "low-budget" tag for this question

Answer (score 3):

The SM81 is a classic "small-diaphragm condensor" microphone.  Search for this term on Sweetwater or other pro-audio store site and you will find that it is a densely populated space.

The SM81 is a popular mic that has been around a long time, so you can probably find one used for a bit cheaper.

To stay with new mics, you can find something like the Audio-Technica 450 for about $250, Rode NT5-S for a bit over $200, the Avantone CK-1 for about $150, and on down the scale.  All of them have something to offer; [GearSlutz](http://gearslutz.com) will have a boatload of opinion about any particular one.

Comment: The Rode NT5-S is an excellent alternative; I've seen it used for choirs, drum overheads and acoustic guitars. It has a nice, neutral character, and it comfortably fits in your pocket. :)